# Nested classes in AdWords Script (JavaScript) - access parent properties

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a JS "class" `agg1Group` that contains data for several keywords with unique id.

Now I want to create a class `getKwData` that represents one keyword in `agg1Group`.

I've tried the following, but it seems that I cannot access the "parent properties", that is the data stored in `agg1Group` from within `getKwData`.

Please find the code below :

```
function agg1Group(kwGroupFromKwContainer, agg1Type) {
    this.kwReportData = {"123124-1242154":"test"};
}
agg1Group.prototype = {
    getKwData: function(id) {
        //test
        Logger.log(this.kwReportData[id]);
    },
}

function main() {
    db = new agg1Group;
    db.getKwData("123124-1242154"); // => test
    kw = new db.getKwData("123124-1242154"); // TypeError: Cannot read property "123124-1242154" from undefined. (line 7)
}
```

I know I could define `getKwData` outside of `agg1Group` and pass `db` as variable. This is not what I want.

I am very new to the use of classes (or instantiating objects to use the proper wording)

I know that inheritance is a big topic but I don't understand yet how it works and what it is used for.

Maybe my problem can somehow be solved using inheritance?

Comment: Don't nest classes. Don't inherit classes. You need simple composition - instances of the one class containing instances of another class.

Comment: @Bergi: So what would you suggest? I do not want to pass `db` (or `this`) as a variable to another function, because its content is huge and I fear it would take too much time/ memory.

Comment: Yes you should do exactly that. Passing objects around means passing references around, there is no copying involved (taking neither time nor memory).